# Searching for audio

Tags: search, audio, signals, signal-processing

I am looking for a toolkit or library to search contents of audio files for am audio sample. 
For example I have 5 seconds of speech that I know it exists in **hundreds of hours of audio**, and I want to find exact file and position of this sub-samples.
The sample is %99 similar but maybe converted to different audio format so it may have **minor differences in waveform**.

I prefer .NET library if there is such an option.

Thank you.

Comment: What methods have you considered so far ? Autocorrelation ? Feature extraction and template matching ?

Comment: Thank you Paul. Do you have any sources on AutoCorrelation?

Comment: Well you could start with the Wikipedia page on autocorrelation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation

Comment: I second autocorrelation as the most simple approach, given your description. It will give you a good estimate of the most likely location of your speech sample.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not an easy DSP problem to solve, and there is no one foolproof method. There is however an excellent recent article on [audio fingerprinting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/duplicates.aspx) on codeproject which goes into some depth on an algorithm that searches for duplicate MP3s, with code in C#. You may be able to adapt the algorithm to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the help I'll check it and leave a comment here.

Comment: I checked the project, it's not suitable for this purpose, it's just good for finding duplicate songs.